# Gradle set JVM agrument for JavaExec task

Tags: java, gradle, jvm

I've got a gradle task. The gradle task should run (in command line mode) with some arguments (JVM parameters)

Gradle task:

```
    task run(type: JavaExec) {
     depends on build
     //That's working fine when I run it by IDEA (gradle)
     systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
     //I need to run it in command line like gradlew run -Dspring.profiles.active (it is possible by Properties - but it both cases argumens are in project.properties
     classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
     mainClass = "com.test.MainClassToRun"
}
```

I can get any args via args / project.getProperty('spring....'). However how I can pass it to JavaExec (main class)?

**RESOLVED (at least that what I was looking for...)**

Launch gradle in this way

```
gradlew stress -Pprofile="STRESS"
```

Gradle task:

```
task run(JavaExec) {
         def profile = project.getProperty("project") //you might check with if(project.hasProperty('profile'))
         .....
         classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
         mainClass = "com.test.MainClassToRun"
         jvmArgs += '-Dspring.profiles.active=' + project


}
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for JavaExec: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html. You can call JavaExec methods inside the braces to configure your task of type JavaExec.